# Does the Java API for Rocks DB support the API GetUpdatesSince?

Tags: java, rocksdb

Does the Java API support the concept of getting all records after a certain point in time?

The RocksDB documents read:

"Incremental Backups and Replication need to be able to find and tail all the recent changes to the database. The API GetUpdatesSince allows an application to tail the RocksDB transaction log." from https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/RocksDB-Basics

The GetUpdatesSince API does not seem to be available in the RocksDB Java API. Is there another way to do this in Java?

Answer (score 4):

There is no other way to achieve the same behavior in Java like using the `GetUpdatesSince` functionality.

`GetUpdatesSince` is available in the Java API of RocksDB. You can call the method on an open `RocksDB` instance. After calling this method a `TransactionLogIterator` is retrieved which can be used to fetch updates since a `Sequence Number` offset. A `TransactionLogIterator` can fetch also updates which happened after the `TransactionLogIterator` was initialized (An example outlining this can be found within the tests).

The latest sequence number of a `RocksDB` instance can be retrieved using `getLatestSequenceNumber`.

**Important** to note is that the following `Options` (`DBOptions`) settings must be set to an appropriate value:

- setWalTtlSeconds
- setWalSizeLimitMB

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GetWritesSince is [being worked on](https://reviews.facebook.net/D32151), but as of today is not complete.